# Getting Error Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to implement facebook login in my unity project. Everything works fine in editor i.e. logging in using editor works fine but when trying to do the same with apk , it crashes after I invoke the logging procedure.

This is what google crashlytics reported about the crash -

`No virtual method registerForActivityResult(Landroidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContract;Landroidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCallback;)Landroidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher; in class Lcom/facebook/login/LoginFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.login.LoginFragment' appears in /data/app/~~5Q7U56IhDJWLs7NgiW1kzA==/com.DefaultCompany.ARTestApp-qBfXPRYlcXThBFc53JFwvA==/base.apk)`

````
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:2414)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1418)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut (FragmentTransition.java:1195)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments (FragmentTransition.java:1078)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions (FragmentTransition.java:117)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2408)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2366)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2273)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3273)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:3229)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:201)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:620)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1485)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:8143)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3797)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:221)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:201)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:173)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2336)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:257)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8246)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:626)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1016)```
````

Comment: Maybe it is related to proguard or missing aar file. Use proguard in your build and resolve all dependencies

Comment: @Jaimin yup there was a missing aar which led to this error. Now it is Solved. Thanks for the help.